# Display the store views depending on I.P address

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, geoip

we have **2 store views for 2 countries** [India & USA ] with store view codes `sv1 & sv2`

what we want is ,

if customer visit the site from USA, it should open USA store-view

if customer visit the site from India, it should open Indian store-view

by checking IP address, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to do that you will need a GeoIp module.

A good resource can be found here: https://www.atwix.com/magento/geoip-magento-store-switcher/

First you'll have to install the GitHub module: https://github.com/tim-bezhashvyly/Sandfox_GeoIP

Then you will have to synchronize the IP database under **System Configuration->General->Countries Options**

From that point you will need to create your own module with the following helper:

```
/* app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/Helper/Data.php */
class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const DEFAULT_STORE = 'English';

    /**
     * countries to store relation
     * default is English
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_countryToStore = array(
        'US' => 'sv2',
        'IN' => 'sv1'
    );

    /**
     * get store view name by country
     * @param $country
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getStoreByCountry($country)
    {
        if (isset($this->_countryToStore[$country])) {
            return $this->_countryToStore[$country];
        }
        return self::DEFAULT_STORE;
    }
}
```

Then you will need to observer the `controller_action_postdipatch` event to redirect your customers:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/etc/config.xml-->       
<config>
 ...
    <global>
    ...
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch>
                <observers>
                    <atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
                        <class>atwix_ipstoreswitcher/observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPostdispatch</method>
                    </atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Finally your observer:

```
/* app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/Model/Observer.php */

class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * redirects customer to store view based on GeoIP
     * @param $event
     */
    public function controllerActionPostdispatch($event)
    {
        $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
        if ($cookie->get('geoip_processed') != 1) {
            $geoIPCountry = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
            $countryCode = $geoIPCountry->getCountry();
            if ($countryCode) {
                $storeName = Mage::helper('atwix_ipstoreswitcher')->getStoreByCountry($countryCode);
                if ($storeName) {
                    $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeName, 'code');
                    if ($store->getName() != Mage::app()->getStore()->getName()) {
                        $event->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($store->getCurrentUrl(false));
                    }
                }
            }
            $cookie->set('geoip_processed', '1', time() + 86400, '/');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for nice answer , i tried a lot from past hours. 
seems i am missing some where. its not working for me

Comment: i set up like this : http://prnt.sc/aya5bh &  code : `'US' => 'sv9',
 'IN' => 'sv9',
 'Fr' => 'sv9'` in `Data.php`

Comment: i am in india, whenever i opened site, it should display currency - "Japanese yen" , but its not displaying.

Comment: @BabyInMagento Try adding some `Mage::log()` in the observer to check the following variables `$countryCode`, & `$storeName`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sWfGqiNW please chekc this , i added code at end of the file

Comment: @BabyinMagento end of file won't help you, you need to add those lines right after the variable declarations.

Comment: i added like [here](http://pasted.co/cf73b03c) can you check [link](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/say-cheese-pink-apple-iphone-6s-phone-case.html)

Comment: @BabyinMagento try to debug using this code instead: http://pasted.co/a0f54a06

Comment: i updated your code : [link](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/say-cheese-pink-apple-iphone-6s-phone-case.html)

Comment: @BabyinMagento what do you want me to do with this link ? The `Mage::log()` will add some information in your `var/log/system.log` file. Start debugging based on the values logged for those variables, it should help you finding what's wrong with your config.

Comment: it created only exception.log file & those errors are from different extension. also when you opened
the link, what currency displayed to you ?

Comment: US dollars with Indian language

Comment: here : http://prnt.sc/ayaidk i clicked on "synchronize" button only one time & clicked on "save config".

Comment: pls visit [site](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/) and tell me what language is displaying for you in top left ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento France, so it's displaying my country, seems to work fine =)

Comment: I was wrong, you are not a star , but superstar :-)